# MethodInvoker não atualiza listBox C#

Tags: c#, thread, timer

Como implementar um timer que a cada ciclo atualiza uma listbox em c#;

Método para criar o timer:

```
private void CriaTimer()
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.Interval = 100;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    AtualizaControlesForm();
}
```

Método para atualizar os componentes:

```
public void AtualizaControlesForm()
{
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.lblPorcentagemGeracao.Text = UtilidadesGeraSped.valorProgressoGeracao + "%"));
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.listBoxInformacoesLog.DataSource = Mensagens.logErroseInfo));
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.listBoxInformacoesLog.Refresh()));
}
```

Está atualizando o textLabel, mas não atualiza o listBox;

Comment: Isto está parecendo tão gambiarra.

Comment: Por que você atualiza a lista a cada X segundos e não quando a lista é de fato modificada? Está usando WPF ou Windows Forms?

Comment: Como que atualiza a cada modificação? Estou usando Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

O `listbox` observa alterações no objeto que você está passando para a propriedade `Datasource`, ficar setando o mesmo objeto não adianta, o objeto em si tem que ser modificado.

Uma solução é utilizar a classe `BindingList`, toda vez que um item for adicionado a ela, o listbox será informado automaticamente:

`BindingList` é uma classe do namespace `System.ComponentModel`.

**Exemplo:**

```
// TipoDoDado é o tipo do item que vai no seu listbox, 
// no seu caso é o item dentro da lista logErroseInfo.
static BindingList<TipoDoDado> data = new BindingList<TipoDoDado>();

MeuConstrutor()
{
    this.listBoxInformacoesLog.Datasource = data;
}

private void CriaTimer()
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.Interval = 100;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    AtualizaControlesForm();
}

public void AtualizaControlesForm()
{
   Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.lblPorcentagemGeracao.Text = UtilidadesGeraSped.valorProgressoGeracao + "%"));

   // Adicione aqui novos itens a lista 
   // Ex.: data.Add(novoItem);
}
```

Comment: Sabe se a propriedade de BindingList estiver em projeto diferente funciona? Estou trabalhando com dois projeto, um projeto principal e outro que seria o form;

Comment: Funciona sim, você só precisa da instância de uma `BindingList` e preencher com os itens que quer exibir e associar ao Datasource, a localização da instância no projeto é indiferente. Você pode passar por parâmetro para o form se quiser.